# Grails Spring Security Rest - 403 Forbidden

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

So I just started learning Grails, and I am trying incorporate the Spring Security REST plugin into my app, the plugin is installed in addition to spring security core which is working. In my REST client, when I hit "api/login" I am able to get an access token and it says I have the role of "ROLE_ADMIN", but then when I try to hit something using that, I keep getting a 403 Forbidden. In Postman, the REST client I am using, I have my Authorization header with "Bearer {key}", with my url of "http://localhost:8080/test/api/secret" and it gives the 403 error. I am trying to setup the log4j logging to see any other issues, but does anyone know what I should look into, any help would be appreciated. I provided my classes below if that helps, I generally used default values for everything such as the UrlMappings.

RandomController.groovy

```
package test

import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured

@Secured(['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'])
class MyController {

    @Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])
    def secret() {
        render "You have ACCESS!!!"
    }
}
```

Bootstrap.groovy

```
class BootStrap {

def init = { servletContext ->

    def adminRole = new SecRole(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save(flush: true)

    def testUser = new SecUser(username: 'bob', password: 'test')
    testUser.save(flush: true)

    SecUserSecRole.create testUser, adminRole, true
}
def destroy = {
}
}
```

UrlMappings.groovy

```
class UrlMappings {

static mappings = {
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }

    "/api/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{ constraints { // apply constraints here
    } }

    "/"(view:"/index")
    "500"(view:'/error')
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For what I can see from the code you posted, if you invoke url http://localhost:8080/test/api/secret, it should execute default action (maybe index) in `SecretController` but the controller you posted is called MyController.

To investigate further, you should enable more verbose logging using log4j configuration as suggested in the doc http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/1.5.1/docs/guide/debugging.html